# Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь с помощью регулярных выражений проверять ввод на валидность. При вводе английских букв все работает, но стоит ввести русские буквы или цифры то уже выбивает ошибка. С цифрами понятно почему, потому что я их и не проверяю в регулярном выражении, а вот буквы русского алфавита почему то не воспринимает. Проверял на сайте regex101, там шаблон работает с английскими и русскими. Когда исключение попадает в блок else в нижеприведенном фрагменте выбивает ошибку как на скриншоте[image: ошибка]:

```
        try
    {
        string pattern = "^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$";       //Поиск символов и пробелов
        regex first_option(pattern);
        smatch matches;
        if (regex_match(value, matches, first_option) && value != "")
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Ошибка";
        }
    }
    catch (string message)
    {
        cout << message << endl;
    }
```

Я так понимаю ошибка кроется в строке `throw "Ошибка"`, но как тогда выбрасывать и перехватывать исключение? Я испытывал вариант `throw new exception("Ошибка")`, и в блоке `catch` было `exception &ex` но судя по всему в блок `catch` это уведомление не доходит. Оно происходит до него. Кто сталкивался с таким? **На комментарии не обращайте внимания я несколько раз менял шаблон поиска.**
Вот прикладываю листинг кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct MyStruct
{
public:
    static string checkStringReturn()
    {
        string value;
        cin >> value;
        try
        {
            string pattern = "^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$";       //Поиск символов и пробелов
            regex first_option(pattern);
            smatch matches;
            if (regex_match(value, matches, first_option) && value != "")
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw "Ошибка";
            }
        }
        catch (string message)
        {
            CommonFunctions::formattOutputLn(message);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    MyStruct::checkStringReturn();
    system("pause");
}
```

Конкретно не могу разрешить проблему с отловом исключения.

Comment: Это вопрос про регулярку или про отлов исключения?

Comment: @user7860670 отлов исключения

Comment: Дело в кодировке. Для символов национальных алфавитов используется 2 байта.

Comment: Ну тогда вам стоило сократить код выкинув из него несущественные в контексте этого вопроса куски. Собственно для перехвата исключения необходимо перехватывать корректный тип. `"Ошибка"` - это не разу не `string`. лучше бросайте `::std::runtime_error{"description"}` и перехватывайте `catch(::std::runtime_error const & exception)`

Comment: "Ошибка" имеет тип  const char*, а вы пытаетесь ловить string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя не доходит в `catch (string message)`, т.к. не ловит ошибку с типом данных `string`. Наведи на русский текст на строке `throw "Ошибка";` и тебе покажет возвращаемый тип данных и он будет `const char*`. Я понимаю, что часто можно было заметить, как `string` приравнивался к `char` или же наоборот, но это работает из-за перегрузки операторов, а `throw` возвращает конкретный тип и здесь нет никаких перегрузок. На будущее, у тебя был факт того, что исключение не доходит до `catch` и на пути 100% нет других "сетей" для отловки исключений, значит условие принимаемых данных, которые ты предоставляешь `(string message)` не подходит и нужно использовать другой тип данных, т.к. преобразования здесь нет, как оказалось.

**Итог таков - нужно писать так:**

```
try
{...}
catch (const char* message)
{...}
```